# Sort String with possible numbers in it

Tags: java, string, sorting

I've got the following possible addresses as string (not sorted):

```
"road 21"
"road 1"
"road 186"
"road +21 / 23"
"road +21 / 19"
"another road 21"
"another road 1"
```

and I want to be able to sort them as (so not on the default String sorting way):

```
another road 1
another road 21
road 1
road 21
road +21 / 19
road +21 / 23
road 186
```

How should I do this? I probably have to use a custom comparator, but how should I split the String?

Comment: I would think `road 186` would come before `road +21 / 19`. Unless you are counting the + as part of the number 21 (in other words, ignoring it, since it doesn't affect the number).

Comment: is that what you are looking for http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)?

Comment: road 186 should be before +21 and I'm indeed ignoring the +. It's just a format they sometimes use over here. @user902383: I know the split with regex exists but I actually haven't got any idea on how to write a regex for this part :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I implemented this in Java and I know it looks weird at first.

If you have any questions feel free to ask me

```
public class SpecialComparator implements Comparator<String> {

   @Override
    public int compare(String arg0, String arg1) {
     // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     String []words1=arg0.split(" ");
     String [] words2 = arg1.split(" ");
     int i = 0;

        if (words1[i].hashCode()>words2[i].hashCode()){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (words1[i].hashCode()<words2[i].hashCode()){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (words1[i].hashCode()==words2[i].hashCode())
            return compare(arg0.substring(i+1, arg0.length()), arg1.substring(i+1,arg1.length()));
        else if (i == Math.min(words1.length,words2.length)-1 && Math.min(words1.length,words2.length) == words1.length){
            return -1;
        }
        else if (i == Math.min(words1.length,words2.length)-1 && Math.min(words1.length,words2.length) == words2.length){
            return 1;
        }
        else if (i == Math.min(words1.length,words2.length)-1 && words1.length == words2.length){
            return 0;
        }
        else{
            return 0;
        }


   }


   public static void main (String[] args){
    ArrayList<String> input = new ArrayList<String>();
    SpecialComparator a = new SpecialComparator();
    input.add("road 21");
    input.add("road 1");
    input.add("road 186");
    input.add("road +21 / 23");
    input.add("road +21 / 19");
    input.add("another road 21");
    input.add("another road 1");
    Collections.sort(input,a);
    for (String ans : input){
        System.out.println(ans);
    }

  }



 }
```

Comment: This sorts my case 100% perfect. Thanks! I was changing the "NaturalOrderComparator" implementation but since this is working I'm using your code. Thanks

Comment: It was fun doing this exercise.

Answer (score 1):

Your format seems to be :

- {name}
- {number}
- optional slash character
- Optional second {number}.

Hence, I would create an object representing this format with those attributes:

```
public class MyInput {
  private String name;
  private Integer firstNumber;
  private Integer secondNumber;
}
```

Then parse your input file to create a `List<MyInput>`.

Finally, you create a custom `Comparator` can call `Collections.sort(yourList, yourCustomComparator)`

Answer (score 0):

This issue seems to crop up alot. I have been using Martin Pools NaturalOrderCompartor. You can easily port it into your code.

https://github.com/paour/natorder/blob/master/NaturalOrderComparator.java

Comment: Doens't sort it perfectly but it's almost there. Guessing it's ok in a lot of situations.

Answer (score 0):

it is little bit nasty, but this is my solution for your problem

```
List<String> list = Arrays.asList("road 21", "road 1", "road 186",
                "road +21 / 23", "road +21 / 19", "another road 21",
                "another road 1");

        Collections.sort(list, new Comparator<String>() {

            Integer toNumber(String string) {
                try {
                    return Integer.parseInt(string);
                } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                String[] left = o1.split("\\s+");
                String[] right = o2.split("\\s+");
                for (int i = 0; i < Math.min(left.length, right.length); i++) {
                    String ls = left[i];
                    String rs = right[i];

                    Integer li = toNumber(ls);
                    Integer ri = toNumber(rs);

                    if (li != null && ri != null
                            && li.intValue() != ri.intValue()) {
                        return li.intValue() - ri.intValue();
                    } else if (li != null && ri == null) {
                        return 1;
                    } else if (li == null && ri != null) {
                        return -1;
                    } else if (li == null && ri == null){
                        int compared = ls.compareToIgnoreCase(rs);
                        if (compared != 0) {
                            return compared;
                        }
                    }

                }
                return left.length - right.length;
            }
        });
```

but if you are ok with changing your structure, then go with solution proposed by Arnaud Denoyelle

Comment: I actually can't change the structure. Otherwise I might prefer his solution indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try following comparator :

```
class MyComparator implements Comparator<String> {

    @Override
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
        o1 = o1.replace("+", "");
        o2 = o2.replace("+", "");

        String[] a1 = o1.split(" ");
        String[] a2 = o2.split(" ");
        int length = (a1.length > a2.length) ? a2.length : a1.length;

        for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
            if (!a1[i].equalsIgnoreCase(a2[i])) {
                if (!isIntegerRegex(a1[i]) || !isIntegerRegex(a2[i])) {
                    return o1.compareTo(o2);
                }
                int f = Integer.parseInt(a1[i]);
                int s = Integer.parseInt(a2[i]);
                return f - s;
            }
        }

        return a1.length - a2.length;
    }

    public boolean isIntegerRegex(String str) {
        return str.matches("^[0-9]+$");
    }
}
```

And call it:

```
public String[] sortStrings(String[] input) {
    Arrays.sort(input, new MyComparator());
    return input;
}
```